# What does colon mean in this conservation of energy equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation, physics

What does the colon (:) mean in the following equation pertaining to conservation of energy?

$$p\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}-\nabla \cdot q -\tau \color{red}{:} \nabla v - ph = 0$$

The term $\tau : \nabla v$ is supposed to describe thermal power caused by movement of gas.

---

$p\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$ is change in internal energy.

$\nabla \cdot q$ is heat flux.

$\tau : \nabla v$ is thermal power caused by movement.

$ph$ is heat sources.

$p$ is density.

$E$ is internal energy.

$\vec{q}$ is "flow of heat through the boundary".

$\tau$ is a stress tensor.

$v$ is velocity.

$h$ is internal heat sources.

Comment: That must be a typo, but please give more context.

Comment: This is useless information.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What kind of context?

Comment: Details on this term and the notation.

Comment: It would be nice to know what each symbol denotes and whether it is a scalar field or a vector field. I assume that $p$ denotes pressure.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But I thought people would recognize "conservation of energy DE". So this just uses some alternative form to it, it should have the same terms?

Comment: @mavavilj: there are million types of energy conservation equations. I am not asking "for fun". If you struggle to provide no details, I can struggle to not answer.

Comment: Some use the colon ":" to denote the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) of two matrices.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Might that be it? Since $\tau$ is a stress tensor, which is a matrix.

Comment: @mavavilj And $\nabla v$ is a Jacobian matrix. The Frobenius inner product takes two matrices and produces a scalar. That could be it.

Comment: AFAIR tensor contraction may be denoted in such a way

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in numerous comments: the colon most likely stands for double contraction between two rank-2 tensors or equivalently the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product).